# Proper use of Typeahead?

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a remote Typeahead example up and running. However, I'm wondering if I'm using it for its intended purposes.

Essentially, even though it displays the appropriate content, I need the unique identifier of the data displayed to be submitted.

The remote URL will return something like this:

```
[{"id":"123456789", "email":"me@server.com", "value":"Me Lastname"}]
```

So, display `Me Lastname`, but actually submit `123456789`?

My gut is telling me I need something else, maybe something like this:
[Select2](https://select2.github.io/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following jQuery/Bootstrap3 library: [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [custom events](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events) of `typeahead` doing something like this:

```
.typeahead({
 ......
},
{
 .......
})
.on('typeahead:selected', onSelected);
```

please nothe that `.on`, it will trig a custom function like this one:

```
function onSelected($e, datum){
  //do your stuff depending on your implementation
  // you might want to fill an hidden field with the id
  // and submitting your form, or something else.
  // you can access your json in this way
  console.log(id); //="123456789
  console.log(email); //="me@server.com
  console.log(value); //="Me Lastname"
```

[here](http://eric.sau.pe/using-twitter-typeahead-js-custom-event-triggers/) you can find some examples

Comment: I ended up using http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ which has the behavior that I'm looking for out of the box. It also works with Bootstrap3. Thanks for the reply.